# MongoDB - Get the document from the collection with field value based on the document from another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections like this:

collection_1

```
[
  {
    name: "p1",
    use: "u1"
  },
  {
    name: "p2",
    use: "u2"
  }, 
  ...
]
```

collection_2

```
[
  {
    user_name: "p1",
    user_id: "Id1"
    date: "DATE"
  },
  {
    user_name: "p2",
    user_id: "Id2"
    date: "DATE"
  },
  {
    user_name: "p3",
    user_id: "Id1"
    date: "DATE"
  }, 
  ...
]
```

I wanted the `favorite` field as boolean if the `collection_1` `name` field matches the `collection_2` `user_name` field and where `user_id` is equal to "Id1".

Is this possible in aggregation or other better methods in MongoDB?

Result

```
[
  {
    name: "p1",
    is_favorite: true
  },
  {
    name: "p2",
    is_favorite: false,
  },
  {
    name: "p2",
    is_favorite: true,
  }
]
```

Comment: Not understand why the last document in the result was with `name: "p2"` and `is_favorite: true`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$lookup` - Collection **col1** (with key: `name`) join with **col2** (with key: `user_name`).
2. `$project` - Decorate the output documents. For the `is_favorite` field, use the `$in` operator to check whether `Id1` is in the `col2.user_id` array.

```
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "col2",
      localField: "name",
      foreignField: "user_name",
      as: "col2"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      is_favorite: {
        $in: [
          "Id1",
          "$col2.user_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N1_p8sO0peK)